# PyMySQL Data Handling to Python

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm trying to grab a single number from MySQL through python - I need that number in a later action. But I can't quite figure out how to only grab the number.

using PyMySQL:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Read a single record
        sql = "SELECT 'data' FROM DB ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        print(result)
```

Always returns {'ID: 101, 'data': 1} when printed - I just want that #1 read into python as an integer.

I have tried picking it out using the list indexing but I'm getting a key error.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
number=result['data']
```

I suggest you use iPython or Jupiter Notebook - to explore the data structures so you can manipulate them interactively.

Or use a GUI like PyCharm which would assist you in this.

Answer (score 0):

Ive sorted this out...

- remove the ' ' from after the SELECT statement, it was just returning the column title
- use the str() function
- then use .contains to search for the integer i was using as a tag to activate a certain case in later if statements